# Conway's Game of Life Python / PyGame printing error

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to python and PyGame and wanted to get some experience by doing what i thought would be a simple project. I can't tell if my error is in my game logic or my PyGame printing. I created two function, one that fills the grid with random values and one that fills the grid with a "Blinker". The program runs without error, however, the rules of the game are not followed. For example, When the "blinker" is set, the program's second frame clears the screen instead of rotating the "blinker".
Any help diagnosing this problem would be appreciated!

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Sizes
size = (600, 600)
width = 20
height = 20
margin = 1
x_size = 600 / width
y_size = 600 / height


def init_grid():
    return [[0 for x in range(x_size)] for y in range(y_size)]


def make_spinner(grind):
    grid[0][0] = 1
    grid[10][10] = 1
    grid[10][11] = 1
    grid[10][12] = 1


def random_grid(grid):
    for x in range(x_size):
        for y in range(y_size):
            grid[x][y] = random.randint(0, 1)


def print_grid(screen, grid):
    for x in range(x_size):
        for y in range(y_size):
            if grid[x][y] == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(
                    screen, BLACK, (x * width, y * height, width, height))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(
                    screen, BLACK, (x * width, y * height, width, height), margin)


def count_neighbours(grid, x, y):
    count = 0
    for i in range(-1, 1):
        for j in range(-1, 1):
            count += grid[x + i][y + j]
    return count - grid[x][y]


def update_grid(grid):
    next_grid = init_grid()
    for x in range(x_size):
        for y in range(y_size):
            if x == 0 or x == x_size - 1 or y == 0 or y == y_size - 1:
                next_grid[x][y] = 0
            else:
                count = count_neighbours(grid, x, y)
                value = grid[x][y]
                if value == 1 and (count == 2 or count == 3):
                    next_grid[x][y] = 1
                elif value == 0 and count == 3:
                    next_grid[x][y] = 1
                else:
                    next_grid[x][y] = 0

    return next_grid


# Initialise game engine
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("The Game of Life")
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
grid = init_grid()
# random_grid(grid)
make_spinner(grid)

# Game loop
while running:

    # Check for exit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    print_grid(screen, grid)
    next_grid = update_grid(grid)
    pygame.display.update()
    grid = next_grid
    clock.tick(2)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message and stack trace or a detailed description of the problem (if you don't get any errors).

Comment: No error, but either the game logic is incorrect or the pygame implementation is incorrect. I updated my description. Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far to diagnose the problem yourself, and what did you find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your count_neighbors function doesn't iterate over the right cells. `range(-1,1)` iterates over `{-1,0}` *not* `{-1,0,1}`.

Instead, use:

```
def count_neighbours(grid, x, y):
    count = 0
    for i in range(-1,2):
        for j in range(-1,2):
            count += grid[x + i][y + j]
    return count - grid[x][y]
```

Comment: Thank you! New to python from Java and C. Now i understand the loops!